# How to store user selected product in php

Tags: php, database, online-store

I create an online store website

 when user add some product to cart i save this information in session (if user not logged in) 

and

when user logged in and select some product i insert them into table

is this true way?

can i store all information of user selected product in session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to go in this case is not using the database at all, but use cookies instead.

[PHP Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

This way you don't have to query the database, and all data will be saved on the computer of the user. This will also keep the information for the people who are not logged in. Which will be more user  friendly.

Comment: can user disable cookie in his/her browser?

Comment: @user Then sessions won't work either; this is not something you need to worry about in practice, as the modern web is basically broken without cookies.

Comment: He could, but not a lot of users do this. But a session will also get destroyed when he browser is closed.

Comment: @Kevin Only if you configure the session cookie that way. Session cookies don't have to be discarded when the browser closes, that's an old myth/misunderstanding.

Comment: I was talking about the session that gets destroyed :-) He was wondering what would happen if the user deleted/turned of cookies.

Comment: @Kevin Still not true. Sessions live server-side, and the server has no clue when exactly the browser is being closed. Session cookies holding the server-side session id live browser-side, and they do not have to be discarded on browser close either.

Comment: @deceze  session cookies are usually sent without an expire time which means they are deleted when the browser is closed. A server can tell very well when a connection is lost.

Comment: @Kevin *"Usually"*, yes, but that means it's *configurable*. And the server-side session is not discarded when "the connection is lost"! The connection is lost every time the page load finishes; that's no indication. The server-side session is *garbage collected* after a specific timeout of no activity; which is also *configurable*. Sessions *can* be configured to be valid indefinitely, period.

Answer (score 1):

Better to store items in **session** (for both visitors or logged in people)

Only needeed of store them is only when they intend to buy the product.

On visit (**even if user is loged in or not**) *you donot have to store them* in db.

Further, use **db** only for values you have to **refer in future**.